# How to delete rows if any cell is empty in python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

We have a csv file, which is retrieved in Python and is initialized as a dataframe. In the csv file there are rows, where columns are empty, and we need to delete these rows.

An example of the csv file is:

```
datetime                           a_id       avg_wind   bar   temperature   solar
2019-11-11T19:53:20.430275697Z     weather    3.212      0.0   5.232         0.0
2019-11-11T20:53:20.430275697Z     weather    3.183      0.0   5.205         0.0
2019-11-11T21:53:20.430275697Z
2019-11-11T22:53:20.430275697Z     weather    3.199      0.0   3.454         0.0
2019-11-11T23:53:20.430275697Z     weather    3.188      0.0   3.422         0.0
```

This is how the dataframe is supposed to look like after the row has been removed:

```
datetime                           a_id       avg_wind   bar   temperature   solar
2019-11-11T19:53:20.430275697Z     weather    3.212      0.0   5.232         0.0
2019-11-11T20:53:20.430275697Z     weather    3.183      0.0   5.205         0.0
2019-11-11T22:53:20.430275697Z     weather    3.199      0.0   3.454         0.0
2019-11-11T23:53:20.430275697Z     weather    3.188      0.0   3.422         0.0
```

We have tried the following: `df = df.dropna()`, but that gave us the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dropna'`

**Code: How we are getting the dataframe**

```
def getWeather(self, collection, database):

    print('--------------')
    print('database = ' + database)
    print('collection = ' + collection)

    # Establishing a client connection
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://...")

    # Retrieving records in the collection from a database
    records = client[database][collection]

    # Records in the collection of the database are stored as a list of dictionaries, which is then converted to a dataframe
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(records.find()))

    # Convert dataframe to json
    json_struct = json.loads(dataframe.to_json(default_handler=str, orient="records"))

    dataframe = pd.json_normalize(json_struct)

    # Removing a row if any cells in the row is empty
    dataframe = dataframe.dropna()
```

Comment: How you are getting the `df`?

Comment: Question has been updated with the code of how we are getting the df

Comment: Where you are applying `dropna`?

Comment: Just checked again, and it actually works. Might have had the line of code at the wrong place before